# Clean up function in Javascript Event Listener

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, event-handling

I am trying to refactor a chess game I am currently creating so the code is more flexible and maintainable, while doing this, I came across an event listener which I have no idea on how to make "cleaner". Some of the variable names in the event listener are unintuitive but apart from that, I would like to know how to structure the event listener such that it uses multiple methods. I have previously asked a question on Code Review which is also about refactoring, and contains the code from which this function came from, here is the link: [Object-Oriented JavaScript chess game](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/234430/object-oriented-javascript-chess-game). If you have any questions or clarifications needed about the code, feel free to ask.

`````
  document.addEventListener('click', function(event){
        if(!hasClicked){
          if(event.clientX < 480 && event.clientY < 480 && board[Math.floor(event.clientY / 60)][Math.floor(event.clientX / 60)] != "vacant"){
            if(humanPlayer.indexOf(board[Math.floor(event.clientY / 60)][Math.floor(event.clientX / 60)]) != -1){
              canMove = true;
              isHighlightPossibleMoves = true;
              hasClicked = true;
              highlightPos = {x: Math.floor(event.clientX / 60), y: Math.floor(event.clientY / 60)};
              pieceMoves = processMoves({x: Math.floor(event.clientX / 60), y: Math.floor(event.clientY / 60)}, board);
            } else {
              hasClicked = true;
              highlightPos = {x: Math.floor(event.clientX / 60), y: Math.floor(event.clientY / 60)};
              canMove = false;
            }
          }
        } else {
          if(canMove){
            advancePosition = {x: Math.floor(event.clientX / 60), y: Math.floor(event.clientY / 60)};
            for(i = 0; i < pieceMoves.moves.length; i++){
              if(advancePosition.x == pieceMoves.moves[i].x && advancePosition.y == pieceMoves.moves[i].y){
                if(board[highlightPos.y][highlightPos.x] == blackKing || board[highlightPos.y][highlightPos.x] == whiteKing){
                  if(pieceMoves.moves[i].x - 2 == highlightPos.x || pieceMoves.moves[i].x + 2 == highlightPos.x){
                    isCastling = true;
                  } else {
                    isCastling = false;
                  }
                }
                if(isCastling){
                  board = chess.returnCastledBoard({x: highlightPos.x, y: highlightPos.y}, pieceMoves.moves[i]);
                  chess = new Chess(board);
                  isCastling = false;
                } else {
                  if(
                    board[highlightPos.y][highlightPos.x] == whiteKingSideCastle ||
                    board[highlightPos.y][highlightPos.x] == whiteQueenSideCastle ||
                    board[highlightPos.y][highlightPos.x] == blackKingSideCastle ||
                    board[highlightPos.y][highlightPos.x] == blackQueenSideCastle ||
                    board[highlightPos.y][highlightPos.x] == blackKing ||
                    board[highlightPos.y][highlightPos.x] == whiteKing
                  ){
                    board[highlightPos.y][highlightPos.x].hasClicked = true;
                  }
                  board = chess.updateBoard(highlightPos, advancePosition);
                  chess = new Chess(board);
                  break;
                }
              }
            }
          }
          hasClicked = false;
          canMove = false;
          highlightPos = undefined;
          pieceMoves = undefined;
          advancePosition = undefined;
        }
      });

````
`````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### *Toward restructuring and optimization*

The expressions **`Math.floor(event.clientX / 60)`** and **`Math.floor(event.clientY / 60)`** which represents element position are redundantly duplicated across a half of the entire posted function's content.
The *Extract function technique* is reasonably applied and expressed with a separate function:

```
function getElPosition(e){
    return {x: Math.floor(e.clientX / 60),
            y: Math.floor(e.clientY / 60)};
}
```

---

`hasClicked` and `highlightPos` variables are assigned with same values in both exclusive branches of `if/else` conditional.
Thus, the assignment statements are moved out as common ones.
Furthermore, both **`highlightPos`** and **`advancePosition`** are essentially point to the target event element position returned by mentioned `getElPosition` function. Therefore, they could be just eliminated (see the full approach below).

---

The condition:

```
if (pieceMoves.moves[i].x - 2 == highlightPos.x || pieceMoves.moves[i].x + 2 == highlightPos.x) {
    isCastling = true;
} else {
    isCastling = false;
}
```

is just a verbose version of:

```
isCastling = (pieceMoves.moves[i].x - 2 == elPos.x || pieceMoves.moves[i].x + 2 == elPos.x);
```

Noisy condition:

```
if (
    board[highlightPos.y][highlightPos.x] == whiteKingSideCastle ||
    board[highlightPos.y][highlightPos.x] == whiteQueenSideCastle ||
    board[highlightPos.y][highlightPos.x] == blackKingSideCastle ||
    board[highlightPos.y][highlightPos.x] == blackQueenSideCastle ||
    board[highlightPos.y][highlightPos.x] == blackKing ||
    board[highlightPos.y][highlightPos.x] == whiteKing
)
```

is replaced with flexible [`Array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) feature:

```
if ([whiteKingSideCastle, whiteQueenSideCastle, blackKingSideCastle, 
     blackQueenSideCastle, blackKing, whiteKing].includes(board[elPos.y][elPos.x]))
```

The `can_move` flag can be eliminated and replaced with check of `pieceMoves.length`.

`board[highlightPos.y][highlightPos.x]` indexing is repeated multiple times and worth to be extracted into a variable:

```
let boardItem = board[elPos.y][elPos.x];
```

---

See the full optimized approach:

```
function getElPosition(e){
    return {x: Math.floor(event.clientX / 60),
            y: Math.floor(event.clientY / 60)};
}

document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    let elPos = getElPosition(event);
    if (!hasClicked) {
        if (event.clientX < 480 && event.clientY < 480 && board[elPos.y][elPos.x] != "vacant") {
            if (humanPlayer.indexOf(board[elPos.y][elPos.x]) != -1) {
                isHighlightPossibleMoves = true;
                pieceMoves = processMoves(Object.assign({}, elPos), board);
            }
            hasClicked = true;
        }
    } else {
        if (pieceMoves && pieceMoves.length) {
            for (let i = 0, len = pieceMoves.moves.length; i < len; i++) {
                let boardItem = board[elPos.y][elPos.x];
                if (elPos.x == pieceMoves.moves[i].x && elPos.y == pieceMoves.moves[i].y) {
                    if (boardItem == blackKing || boardItem == whiteKing) {
                        isCastling = (pieceMoves.moves[i].x - 2 == elPos.x || pieceMoves.moves[i].x + 2 == elPos.x);
                    }
                    if (!isCastling) {
                        if ([whiteKingSideCastle, whiteQueenSideCastle, blackKingSideCastle,
                            blackQueenSideCastle, blackKing, whiteKing].includes(boardItem))
                        {
                            boardItem.hasClicked = true;
                        }
                        board = chess.updateBoard(elPos, elPos);
                        chess = new Chess(board);
                        break;
                    }
                    board = chess.returnCastledBoard({x: elPos.x, y: elPos.y}, pieceMoves.moves[i]);
                    chess = new Chess(board);
                    isCastling = false;
                }
            }
        }
        hasClicked = false;
        pieceMoves = undefined;
    }
});
```

Comment: A function separated from the event listener with a name that's indicative of it's intent would be a good addition to this answer.